# How to wrap Unity3d C# wait instruction (which waits with some yield return) into a saparate function or class?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

So I forund my salfe having alike code repeating 3 times in 3 functions of my class, something like

```
var obj = ...
while (!obj.isDone) {
      yield return obj;
}
```

In Unity3d it is related to AssetBundleRequest, WWW and some other asinc classes. Function from where I call that code returns `IEnumerator` and has much mere  `yield returns` after such `wait` calls. I wonder how to wrap such `wait` into some template function callable from my function with one log `yeld return func<typeof(obj)>(obj)` or something similar that would end only when `obj.isDone`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just `yield return obj;` a single time?  The [doc for AsyncOperation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/AsyncOperation.html), which is where `isDone` is defined, seems to say so, with:

> You can **yield** until asynchronous operation continues...

If not, you could make some code like this:

```
public static IEnumerator UntilDone(AsyncOperation op)
{
  while (!op.isDone) {
    yield return op;
  }
}
//in a method:
yield return StartCoroutine(UntilDone(obj));
```

Comment: BTW is there any option of Starting Coroutines from not MonoBehaviour ?

Comment: I'd suggest keeping a reference to a dummy MonoBehaviour in your non-MonoBehaviour class in order to do StartCoroutine.  Something like `MonoBehaviour dummy;` as a field of your type, then `dummy.StartCoroutine(myRoutine());`